# Convert sphere function to tail recursive function

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I have implemented Sphere function (takes a List of elements, squares every element and returns sum) in Scala. I want to convert this function to tail recursive. My code is here

```
def Sphere(list: List[Double]): Double = {
  val power = list.map(math.pow(_, 2))
  power.reduce(_+_)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like:

```
  @tailrec
  def Sphere(list: List[Double], result: Double = 0): Double = list match {
    case Nil => result
    case x::xs => Sphere(xs, result + math.pow(x, 2))
  }

  println(Sphere(List(1,3,4,5)))
```

With `@tailrec` you make sure  that it is actually tail recursive (the compile will fail).

Important is:

- that the last call is to itself
- that it has the intermediate result in the parameter list
- `x` is the head of the List where you do the calculation
- `xs` is the rest of the List (the **tail**) - where you append the recursive function on - until the List is empty > `Nil`.

Comment: This is working fine. but i am confused about x::xs .

Comment: check for example: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-lists-nil-cons-scala-match-case-expressions

Comment: I also adjusted my answer

Comment: Yes, now it clears to me. I can write it as

    case _ => Sphere(list.tail , result + math.pow(list.head ,2))

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the same function signature, you need to use a nested recursive function:

```
def Sphere(list: List[Double]): Double = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(rem: List[Double], res: Double): Double =
    rem match {
      case hd :: tail => loop(tail, res + hd*hd)
      case _ => res
    }

  loop(list, 0)
}
```

You can write this as a single tail-recursive function but that requires changing the function signature to add a spurious extra parameter. This is arguably bad design because the implementation is leaking out through the interface. This also requires the function to be marked `final` if it is a method.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers above, if you use foldLeft, it's already tail call optimised

```
def Sphere(list: List[Double]): Double = {
    list.foldLeft(0.0)((res, elem) => res + elem * elem)
}
```

It's better to use library versions and not add an extra check (@tailrec) for compiler when stuff's available.

**foldLeft is same as reduceLeft except that it takes an extra initial value as argument and not throw an exception when the collection is empty.

**foldLeft's actual implementation ends up using a while loop for performance reasons, but again that's the benefit of tail recursion, make it as fast as a loop.